# Not able to build for IOS after flutter upgrade to 1.20.2

Tags: ios, flutter, build

I am facing the issue after upgrading to stable flutter version 1.20.2. I am not able to run on IOS. when I start debugging I get this error.

Xcode build done. 48.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Exited (sigterm)
Could not build the application for the simulator.

flutter run -v

[image]

Before that, I was on flutter 1.17.5 and everything was working. It is happening on all of my projects. How to resolve?

Comment: Try deleting podspec and look for the real error, your screenshot only contains unrelated warnings.

Answer (score 1):

It happens to me also after **Upgrading flutter**, My project does not work.Then i create new project and copy paste previous code in new projects.This works for me because previous projects have old dependencies.Try it

Comment: I cannot do that, its a big project under guidelines. What is the solution, why is it happening?  If it's running for android smoothly.

Comment: Create new project and write some code to check whether it works or not .It is happening because after updating,new projects will tackle that change.The old projects have previous dependencies.I don't know other solution I solved my problem by creating new projects